# Python - Email-Sending with smtplib for yahoo not possible?

Tags: python, email, smtplib

i try to send an email using the following code -

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
  path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 
  fn = os.path.join(path, ".env")
  load_dotenv(fn) 
  LOGIN_EMAIL = os.environ.get("LOGIN_EMAIL")
  LOGIN_PW = os.environ.get("LOGIN_PW")
  SMTP_SERVER = os.environ.get("SMTP_SERVER")
  SMTP_PORT = os.environ.get("SMTP_PORT")
  MAIL_TO = os.environ.get("MAIL_TO")

  headlineTxt = "The Headline"
  msgTxt = "This is some Text"
  s = smtplib.SMTP (SMTP_SERVER, str(int(SMTP_PORT)))
  print (s.ehlo ())  # Check if OK - Response 250 means connection is ok
  print (s.starttls ())  # Check if OK
  print (s.login (LOGIN_EMAIL, LOGIN_PW))  # Check if OK
  msg = MIMEText (msgTxt)
  msg['Subject'] = headlineTxt
  msg['From'] = LOGIN_EMAIL
  s.sendmail (LOGIN_EMAIL, MAIL_TO, msg.as_string ())
  s.quit ()
```

When i run this code with a gmail-account:

```
LOGIN_EMAIL = myEMail@gmail.com
LOGIN_PW = myPW
SMTP_SERVER = smtp.gmail.com
SMTP_PORT = 587
MAIL_TO = myEMail@gmx.at
```

this works fine with this output

```
(250, b'smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2a02:1748:dd5c:8830:25e4:8eed:cc33:1bd4]\nSIZE 35882577\n8BITMIME\nSTARTTLS\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nPIPELINING\nCHUNKING\nSMTPUTF8')
(220, b'2.0.0 Ready to start TLS')
(235, b'2.7.0 Accepted')
```

but when i try it with a yahoo-account:

```
LOGIN_EMAIL = myEMail@yahoo.com
LOGIN_PW = myPW
SMTP_SERVER = smtp.mail.yahoo.com
SMTP_PORT = 587
MAIL_TO = myEMail@yahoo.com
```

it didn´t work and i get the following error:

```
(250, b'hermes--production-ir2-5cc57b9c45-hvdt8 Hello DESKTOP-8CPPRED.fritz.box [185.17.14.8])\nPIPELINING\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\n8BITMIME\nSIZE 41697280\nSTARTTLS')
(220, b'2.0.0 Ready to start TLS')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\DEV\Python-Diverses\smtplib\sendEmail.py", line 22, in <module>
    print (s.login (LOGIN_EMAIL, LOGIN_PW))  # Check if OK
  File "C:\Users\marku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 739, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "C:\Users\marku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
    (code, resp) = self.docmd("AUTH", mechanism + " " + response)
  File "C:\Users\marku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 432, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "C:\Users\marku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 405, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

How can i send emails using a yahoo-email?

Comment: Have you also tried port 465?  [Ref](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN4724.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAKzRlvCpbHtGuDWY9pEr9Rq26qV8Ws3zbXkpK__WSVB87a0Ug-x1JPiYbVEAzjOkNfFP4wZnGHLFw_FlVUte4xhYD3LlL073Z2DjV4SGMjr_RnOsWVwRk8-Z4St6R4fQh6kE3TprlYqBr_mLw5iycZBEXlHtQrVxS9R-DEwxq6ok)

Comment: My guess is that your Yahoo password is wrong.  HOWEVER, remember that you can send mail to ANYONE through that gmail account.  If you have one that works, you don't need the other.

Comment: From the reference provided by @JesseSealand above, it hints that Yahoo requires apps that don't use its special login page instead use an app-specific password.  https://help.yahoo.com/kb/generate-manage-third-party-passwords-sln15241.html

Comment: @Jesse Sealand: When i m using port 465 i get an error at line 19: ```$ python sendEMail.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\DEV\Python-Diverses\smtplib\sendEMail.py", line 19, in <module>
    s = smtplib.SMTP (SMTP_SERVER, str(int(SMTP_PORT)))
  File "C:\Users\marku\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 258, in __init__
    raise SMTPConnectError(code, msg)
smtplib.SMTPConnectError: (-1, b'\x02\x01Z\x15\x03\x03\x00\x02\x01\x00')```